# Send POST data with Java

Tags: java, php

Im trying to submit a form from Java with POST. I want to send some values and store them in a sql db on a webserver. I found this example here on stack but I dont understand it properly.

Should the URL refer to the php file that accepts the POST requests? WHat other values here do I have to consider. The params I geuss is ok, they should just match the POST check on my PHP file.

Is this all that is needed to successfully send data with POST from Java to my webserver?

```
URL url = new URL("http://g.php");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("value", 5);
        params.put("id", 17);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            System.out.print((char)c);
```

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same, but annotated:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://g.php"); // URL to your application
    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("value", 5); // All parameters, also easy
    params.put("id", 17);

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    // POST as urlencoded is basically key-value pairs, as with GET
    // This creates key=value&key=value&... pairs
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }

    // Convert string to byte array, as it should be sent
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Connect, easy
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    // Tell server that this is POST and in which format is the data
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    // This gets the output from your server
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        System.out.print((char)c);
```

Comment: thanks. In php I check like this : if(!empty(  $_POST['value'] && $_POST['id'] )){      is this correct? when dealing with POST via java?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't matter if this came from Java or not. But you should use empty() on each value separately: !empty( $_POST['value']) && !emoty($_POST['id'])

Comment: just would like to point out, php has its own way to do this: `isset($variable)` though this will accept the empty string, it checks for the variable existence

Answer (score 0):

The following example worked for me

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/");
// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "Bob"));
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // writing error to Log
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```